# How exactly do I use OpenCV and homographies to undo perspective warp?

Tags: java, opencv, homography

I need to use Java and OpenCV to do the process shown on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_control
I know exactly where the 4 points of my trapezoid are, and I just need them to square up. I've heard I need to use a homography and a warpPerspective command, but I don't know what parameters these use. I don't know HOW to employ them, only that I do need to use them. Can anyone fully explain this? I've never done anything like this, so starting from a bare minimum would be awesome. I'd really like to get into the world of computer vision so having someone to help me out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dont forget to click the `empty check mark` next to the answer if you liked the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their are two methods for doing this:

1) Geometric warping where you use perspective geometry to create the H matrix. OR

2) Using feature matches to create that same H matrix.

Opencv has a nice function called `findHomography` (which is the second method) that takes in 2 arrays. Both arrays should be matching features from the 2 different images.

Once you have the H matrix creating the warped image is also easy and you can just call `warpPerspective` which you store in a matrix which you then `imshow` to see.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on each of your options? Again, I'm an absolute beginner. What is an H matrix? What are feature matches? What arrays do I actually put into the findHomography method? You say "both arrays should be matching features from the 2 different images". What 2 images? I only have source and destination. I can't really use destination when that's what I'm creating, right? Or is the homography meant to translate from one to another? Sorry for being so uninformed.

Comment: The `Homography = H matrix` and that matrix is the Transformation matrix that dictates where one point in one image is in another image. i.e `X1 = H * X2` where X1 is the point in image one and X2 is the point in image 2

Comment: Ah, okay. So the H matrix specifies the "rule"? The system that tells each pixel "You need to move from coordinates (X1,Y1) to (X2,Y2)". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. And the function `warpPerspective` does that for you.

Comment: Okay. So I need to have an H matrix with the 4 corners of the source trapezoid, and an H matrix with the 4 corners of the destination rectangle. Then I pass those both into the warpPerspective function, and that will shift the first image into the shape I want?

Comment: Too create the `H matrix` all you need is 4 points. ANY 4 points in 2 images that match. i.e 4 points from image 1 and 4 points from image 2. That match to each other. Then you can create this image matrix. Obviously you can have more points, the more the better, but all you need is 4.

Comment: Gotcha. How do I declare these 4 points to a homography? I imagine my program has to be able to understand the 4 ordered pairs of coordinates I give to each.

Comment: There are many different ways to get these 4 points. And researchers are constantly trying to find the best way. 1 wait is you can extract `Sift or Surf features` from both images and see if they match. Another way is you can hand pick points from one image and another. The hand picking is the easiest. Just create 2 arrays of `2d points` I think opencv has there own `2d point` class with x y fields. For the locations in the image plane.

Comment: Well, I know what pixel it is. I know the coordinates in the image. The question is how I pass these into the program.